# Is it possible to create a "all keywords in adgroup must contain X"?

Tags: google, google-ads

I run a Google AdWords campaign with (amongst others) the following AdGroups:

```
Accounting
Accounting non profits
```

in each group I have a bunch of keywords. I use broad match with a + before it. Like:

```
+accountingsoftware
+accountingsoftware non profit
```

I have the problem that sometimes phrases that should be matched by the first AdGroup get's matched by the second AdGroup. For example the phrase `simple accounting software` was matched by the AdGroup `accounting non profits`.

I know there are negative keywords, but I would like something like a list of positive keywords. I would like to make it so that unless the word "non profit" or "NGO" etc are in the search phrase, the ads never show up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "phrase matching" in Google Adwords.   It is less strict than "exact match", but more strict than "broad match".  To use phrase matching, the phrase must be in quotes when you bid on it.

If you wanted to phrase match "accounting software" then all the search phrases would include that.  It would match:

- simple accounting software
- accounting software for a business
- download accounting software

But not things that broad match might do such as

- accounting non profits
- software for accounting

[Here is Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497836?hl=en) about different match types.